# HamBurger Icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, hamburger-menu, drawertoggle

I want to use a hamburger icon on the right side of my action bar. But it's showing an arrow sign. I have included Library AppCompatV7 and extending my class from Activity. Can someOne please give the solution. I have tried many solutions but none is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Android Manifest, check what theme you are using. I was using AppTheme for my main activity

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".FrontPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
```

2) Open res/values/styles, make sure your theme includes the attribu "drawerArrowStyle", then create a new style for that to change the value for "spinBars" to true.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

...it took me a while to piece that one together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Russell... I have updated my styles.xml now.. But my app gets crashed when i add that DrawerArrowStyle. Any idea?

Comment: please update your questions with your layout, style, main activity and crash result.